# Sorting a rails created li by date

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, sorting

I'm trying to sort these li's by the date value that rails is generating. The closest I have gotten is something like:

```
<ul id="press-items-ul">
    <% @press.each do |press| %>
        <li class="press-link-li">
            <h2 class="press-source"> <%= link_to press.source, press.link %>  </h2>
            <h2 class="press-title"> <%= link_to press.title, press.link %> </h2>
            <h2 class="press-date"><%= press.date %> </h2>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

The closest I have gotten is something like what is below but that just pulls out the dates, puts then in an array and sorts them with no effect on the actual list item. I don't even need them to be sortable. Only sorted with the most recent entry on top. Any points in the right direction would be much apprecatiated.

```
var elems = $.makeArray($(".press-date"));
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return new Date( $(a).text() ) < new Date( $(b).text() );
});
$(".press-link-li").html(elems);
```

Comment: how you get the `@press`? because if you get from database you can do some like `Pres.where(...).order(:date)` (depend on your variable names)

Comment: Yeah, the @press loop is being created by the rails guy on the server side. I'm hoping to sort it on the front end because I know almost nothing about ruby on rails. That said, that's not much code. So looks way better than waht i'm thinking it would take to do it in js.

Comment: class Press < ActiveRecord::Base
  # validates :title
  # validates :description
  # validates :link

  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>" }

  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
 def self.latest
  Press.order(:date).last
 end
end

Comment: Agreed.   My advice is get the back-end guy to do it.  It should take him minutes to do it.

Comment: I think ordering in js it look ugly. When a user join to the page he look a mess at start and if  your `ul` list is too big and one user have a low hardware pc (extreme situation I know)